# React PureComponent can be slower than Component? How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm referring to a post by Dan Abramov stating:

> PSA: React.PureComponent can make your app slower if you use it everywhere.

[(Dan's tweet on the topic)](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/820668074223353858?lang=en)

Can someone elaborate on this? Thank you.

Comment: as further he says "Think about it. If component’s props are shallowly unequal more often than not, it re-renders anyway, but it also had to run the checks"

Answer (score 2):

PureComponent implements a shouldComponentUpdate with shallow comparison of component state and props. It compares the currentProps against nextProps (similarly for state) and only if there is a change, the render method is invoked. The additional overhead of this comparison would definitely slow down the application especially if your component and state are heavy.

Comment: I think that what's missing in your explanation is the key point that Dan Abramov is stating: that the probability for a component to have to re-render may be higher than not having to re-render. So it's better to avoid unnecessary computations if the outcome is already known. In the end, the person implementing the component can improve performance if she knows how often the props might change.